# Subset n number of rows from a dataframe based on date criterias from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (say Summary) in R:

```
Begin Date | EndDate | Month | Year | Count
2/1/2014 | 1/31/2015 | Jan | 2014 | 10
3/1/2014 | 2/28/2015 | Feb | 2014 | 10
4/1/2014 | 3/31/2015 | Mar | 2014 | 10
5/1/2014 | 4/30/2015 | Apr | 2014 | 10
```

Another dataframe (say terms)

```
Student_Hire_Date | Student_ID
2/1/2014 | 100001
2/2/2014 | 100002
2/3/2014 | 100003
2/4/2014 | 100004
2/5/2014 | 100005
```

I need an R code that will populate the column "Count", by taking a subset of data from the Terms table where Student_Hire_Date is between 'BeginDate' and 'EndDate' from Summary Table.

An R code equivalent to :

```
Summary$Count <- "select count(*) from Terms,Summary 
                  where Terms.Student_Hire_Date between
                      Summary.BeginDate and Summary.EndDate"
                  GROUP BY Summary.EndDate
```

I tried using the following code, but I am getting the same count for every date range.

```
summary$Count <- nrow(subset(Terms, 
                              !is.na(Student_ID)
                               & Student_Hire_Date >= as.Date(Summary$BeginDate)
                                & Student_Hire_Date <= as.Date(Summary$EndDate)
```

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Have you considered the 'sqldf' package?  With it you can just run your sql query as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `sapply` to loop through each row to compare *Summary* row value to *Terms* row value. Right now you are subsetting the same condition for every row of *Summary* since the *BeginDate* and *EndDate* do not match outside row of assigned new column.

```
Summary$Count <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(Summary)), function(i) {
       nrow(subset(Terms, !is.na(Student_ID)
                   & Student_Hire_Date >= Summary$BeginDate[[i]]
                   & Student_Hire_Date <= Summary$EndDate[[i]]))
})
```